# Считывать файли в переменную пока не конец

Tags: python, файлы

Дайте пожалуйста пример. 
нужен цикл с постусловием. В котором в массив считываются строки из файла, построчно. 
Массив:                        `mas_text = []`
Файл откуда будет считываться: `text_file`

Спасибо.

Comment: "Цикл с постусловием" -- это do { ... } while (...) в Си? Если так, то обломитесь.

Comment: да, языковой конструкции нет, но что мешает разрулить это логически?

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in file.xreadlines():
    do_smth()
    post_condition()
```

UPD:

```
mas_text = [line for line in text_file.xreadlines()]
```

UPD2:
а вот красивый вариант с условием, но не факт, что это то, что нужно топикстартеру:

```
mas_text = [post_condition(line) and line for line in text_file.xreadlines()]
```

ну и пост-условие можно сделать анонимной функцией, но эот уже надо конкретно смотреть, что вам надо сделать

Comment: а если надо просто загнать все строки в массив, то ничего проще, чем 

    text = f.readlines()

придумать явно нельзя. Правда, тут есть нюанс с символом перевода строки (она остаётся везде) - она зачастую не нужна.
И если она не нужна, то проще всего воспользоваться следующим способом:

    text = f.read().splitlines()

Comment: >>
а если надо просто загнать все строки в массив, то ничего проще, чем

что заставляет тебя так думать? зачем загружать весь файл в память если можно аккуратно проитерировать по нему?

Comment: +1. Наверное, ещё более по-питоновски было бы применить `map`.

Comment: @VladD
может, всё-таки, не мап, а генератор списка? например:

    mas_text = [line for line in text_file.xreadlines()]

хотя мне кажется, что выглядит как-то кривовато и можно еще проще сделать

можете написать свой вариант с мапом?

Comment: человеку нужно с постусловием, а вы начали рассуждать о красоте перевода файла в массив.

Comment: ну с постусловием -- мой первый отрывок кода

Comment: @spirit: Нет, человеку _не нужно_ с постусловием. Человеку нужно правильно, in a pythonic way.

---
@actionless: А чем это отличается по сути от

    mas_text = text_file.xreadlines()

?

Comment: тем, что mas_text будет итератором, насколько я понимаю

аналог, по-ходу, будет:

    mas_text = list(text_file.xreadlines())

Comment: тем, что у тебя будет не массив.

Comment: @actionless, да, но тогда проще использовать readlines.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам постусловие, чтобы останавливаться где-то? тогда так, учитывая вышесказанное:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def file2list(text_file):
    try:
        f = open(text_file)
    except IOError:
        print "file %s not exist" %text_file
        return 1

    #если просто до конца файла
    mas_text = f.readlines()
    # конец моего первого если

    # если при этом условия
    mas_text = []
    for line in f.xreadlines():
        if line == "начиная с этой не считывать\n":
            f.close()
            return mas_text
        mas_text.append(line)
        if line == "после этой не считывать\n":
            f.close()
            return mas_text
    # конец моего второго если

    f.close()
    return mas_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mas_text = file2list("/tmp/file")
    print mas_text
```

Проверил, в конце строк надо '\n'